# Fatal error crashing on latest version of Java on Windows 10 machine

Tags: java, windows, thread-dump

A customer is seeing this error on Windows 10 Build 1703 machine, I'm not getting it

They got this with Java 1.8.0_111-b14)

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000076fd6adf, pid=3164, tid=0x00000000000027d4
```

I got them to update to the latest version 1.8.0_131-b11 and they still the same error. at least the *pc* part is the same error.

I assume the error is specific to their machine, I have now found some similar issues but with no resolutions.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178846?jql=text%20~%20%22msvcr100.dll%2B0x36adf%22

```
---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 15063 (10.0.15063.0)

CPU:total 12 (initial active 12) (6 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 45 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 33488896k(26044808k free), swap 38469632k(28180956k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_131-b11), built on Mar 15 2017 01:23:53 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Thu May 04 19:57:01 2017
elapsed time: 6 seconds (0d 0h 0m 6s)



#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000076fd6adf, pid=10128, tid=0x0000000000002334
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000002bd5a800):  JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9012, stack(0x0000000035a00000,0x0000000035b00000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000035aff180, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x000000003516f600
RSP=0x0000000035aff128, RBP=0x0000000035aff310, RSI=0x0000000000000108, RDI=0x000000002bd5a9f8
R8 =0x000000003516f600, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000035afc7e0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000035aff330, R14=0x0000000035aff2f8, R15=0x000000002bd5a800
RIP=0x0000000076fd6adf, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000035aff128)
0x0000000035aff128:   00000000764f9d36 0000000000000000
0x0000000035aff138:   000000002bd5a9f8 0000000000000108
0x0000000035aff148:   000000003516f600 000000002bd5a9f8
0x0000000035aff158:   00000000764fa6f9 000000003516f600
0x0000000035aff168:   0000acd1cf8ddc73 0000000000000005
0x0000000035aff178:   000000002bd5a800 0000000000000000
0x0000000035aff188:   0000000000000000 0000000035079900
0x0000000035aff198:   00007ffa5e6fa900 0000000000000000
0x0000000035aff1a8:   0000000000000000 0000000035aff228
0x0000000035aff1b8:   000000000235835d 000000002bd5a800
0x0000000035aff1c8:   0000000076882ac2 0000000000000000
0x0000000035aff1d8:   0000000000000000 000000071c6d5320
0x0000000035aff1e8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000035aff1f8:   000000000289d075 0000000000000058
0x0000000035aff208:   0000000035aff260 000000071c78bd38
0x0000000035aff218:   000000071c78bd98 0000000100000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000076fd6adf)
0x0000000076fd6abf:   99 03 00 cc 33 c0 48 8b 5c 24 40 48 8b 74 24 48
0x0000000076fd6acf:   48 83 c4 30 5f c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 48 8b c1
0x0000000076fd6adf:   0f b7 10 48 83 c0 02 66 85 d2 75 f4 48 2b c1 48
0x0000000076fd6aef:   d1 f8 48 ff c8 c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 45 33 c0 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000035aff180 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002bd5a800
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000003516f600 is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000000035aff128 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002bd5a800
RBP=0x0000000035aff310 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002bd5a800
RSI=0x0000000000000108 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000002bd5a9f8 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000003516f600 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000035afc7e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002bd5a800
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000035aff330 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002bd5a800
R14=0x0000000035aff2f8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002bd5a800
R15=0x000000002bd5a800 is a thread


Stack: [0x0000000035a00000,0x0000000035b00000],  sp=0x0000000035aff128,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 4760  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getDisplayNameOf(JJI)Ljava/lang/String; (0 bytes) @ 0x000000000290f509 [0x000000000290f4c0+0x49]
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$1600(JJI)Ljava/lang/String;+4
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$13.call()Ljava/lang/String;+15
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$13.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
J 4839 C1 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V (126 bytes) @ 0x000000000260f354 [0x000000000260f100+0x254]
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run()V+7
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x000000002bd5a800 JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9012, stack(0x0000000035a00000,0x0000000035b00000)]
  0x000000002bd58000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1884, stack(0x0000000034ca0000,0x0000000034da0000)]
  0x000000002bd55000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=12644, stack(0x00000000309a0000,0x0000000030aa0000)]
  0x000000002bd59000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=4128, stack(0x00000000308a0000,0x00000000309a0000)]
  0x000000002bd56800 JavaThread "derby.rawStoreDaemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15256, stack(0x00000000303a0000,0x00000000304a0000)]
  0x000000002bd53800 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7032, stack(0x00000000302a0000,0x00000000303a0000)]
  0x000000002bd56000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8256, stack(0x000000002ffa0000,0x00000000300a0000)]
  0x000000002bd57800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12188, stack(0x000000002fea0000,0x000000002ffa0000)]
  0x000000002b874800 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8400, stack(0x000000002fda0000,0x000000002fea0000)]
  0x000000002b874000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14180, stack(0x000000002fca0000,0x000000002fda0000)]
  0x000000002b873000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9816, stack(0x000000002fba0000,0x000000002fca0000)]
  0x000000002be8b000 JavaThread "com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10740, stack(0x000000002faa0000,0x000000002fba0000)]
  0x000000002be8a800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16204, stack(0x000000002f9a0000,0x000000002faa0000)]
  0x000000002b16c000 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1664, stack(0x000000002f360000,0x000000002f460000)]
  0x000000002b74e000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=13888, stack(0x000000002cba0000,0x000000002cca0000)]
  0x0000000029e04000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9000, stack(0x000000002c920000,0x000000002ca20000)]
  0x00000000266a8800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9876, stack(0x0000000028090000,0x0000000028190000)]
  0x0000000026640800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11632, stack(0x0000000027f90000,0x0000000028090000)]
  0x000000002663f800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15584, stack(0x0000000027e90000,0x0000000027f90000)]
  0x000000002663a000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12932, stack(0x0000000027d90000,0x0000000027e90000)]
  0x0000000026630000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12308, stack(0x0000000027c90000,0x0000000027d90000)]
  0x0000000026629000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14660, stack(0x0000000027b90000,0x0000000027c90000)]
  0x0000000026628000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14612, stack(0x0000000027a90000,0x0000000027b90000)]
  0x0000000026623000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13460, stack(0x0000000027890000,0x0000000027990000)]
  0x0000000002338800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2892, stack(0x0000000027790000,0x0000000027890000)]
  0x00000000021ad800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=11808, stack(0x0000000000050000,0x0000000000150000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000026602800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000027690000,0x0000000027790000] [id=9800]
  0x00000000266ea800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000028190000,0x0000000028290000] [id=10372]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 153088K, used 52212K [0x0000000719580000, 0x0000000727e80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131584K, 39% used [0x0000000719580000,0x000000071c87d350,0x0000000721600000)
  from space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000721600000,0x0000000721600000,0x0000000722b00000)
  to   space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000726980000,0x0000000726980000,0x0000000727e80000)
 ParOldGen       total 356352K, used 24548K [0x00000005cc000000, 0x00000005e1c00000, 0x0000000719580000)
  object space 356352K, 6% used [0x00000005cc000000,0x00000005cd7f93f8,0x00000005e1c00000)
 Metaspace       used 42080K, capacity 42590K, committed 42920K, reserved 1085440K
  class space    used 6368K, capacity 6535K, committed 6568K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011710000,0x00000000126c0000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000e8b0000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000076f1c720
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000013b30000, 0x000000001b830000)
 End Bits:   [0x000000001b830000, 0x0000000023530000)

Polling page: 0x0000000002160000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=14897Kb max_used=16445Kb free=230862Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002350000, 0x00000000033a0000, 0x0000000011350000]
 total_blobs=5001 nmethods=4288 adapters=624
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 6.316 Thread 0x0000000026640800 4870       3       java.io.File::hashCode (8 bytes)
Event: 6.316 Thread 0x0000000026640800 nmethod 4870 0x0000000002a11a10 code [0x0000000002a11ba0, 0x0000000002a11f78]
Event: 6.316 Thread 0x0000000026640800 4871       3       java.io.WinNTFileSystem::hashCode (17 bytes)
Event: 6.317 Thread 0x0000000026640800 nmethod 4871 0x0000000002a11350 code [0x0000000002a114c0, 0x0000000002a11838]
Event: 6.317 Thread 0x0000000026640800 4872       1       javax.swing.JFileChooser::getFileSystemView (5 bytes)
Event: 6.317 Thread 0x0000000026640800 nmethod 4872 0x0000000002d43f50 code [0x0000000002d440a0, 0x0000000002d441b0]
Event: 6.317 Thread 0x0000000026640800 4873       3       javax.swing.CellRendererPane::addImpl (17 bytes)
Event: 6.317 Thread 0x0000000026640800 nmethod 4873 0x0000000002d43990 code [0x0000000002d43b00, 0x0000000002d43e48]
Event: 6.317 Thread 0x0000000026640800 4874       1       javax.swing.JFileChooser::getFileView (5 bytes)
Event: 6.317 Thread 0x0000000026640800 nmethod 4874 0x0000000002d436d0 code [0x0000000002d43820, 0x0000000002d43930]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 1.636 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 153088K, used 131584K [0x0000000719580000, 0x0000000724000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131584K, 100% used [0x0000000719580000,0x0000000721600000,0x0000000721600000)
  from space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000722b00000,0x0000000722b00000,0x0000000724000000)
  to   space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000721600000,0x0000000721600000,0x0000000722b00000)
 ParOldGen       total 349696K, used 0K [0x00000005cc000000, 0x00000005e1580000, 0x0000000719580000)
  object space 349696K, 0% used [0x00000005cc000000,0x00000005cc000000,0x00000005e1580000)
 Metaspace       used 17251K, capacity 17578K, committed 17792K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 2229K, capacity 2327K, committed 2432K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1.649 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 153088K, used 21503K [0x0000000719580000, 0x0000000724000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131584K, 0% used [0x0000000719580000,0x0000000719580000,0x0000000721600000)
  from space 21504K, 99% used [0x0000000721600000,0x0000000722afff90,0x0000000722b00000)
  to   space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000722b00000,0x0000000722b00000,0x0000000724000000)
 ParOldGen       total 349696K, used 2922K [0x00000005cc000000, 0x00000005e1580000, 0x0000000719580000)
  object space 349696K, 0% used [0x00000005cc000000,0x00000005cc2da948,0x00000005e1580000)
 Metaspace       used 17251K, capacity 17578K, committed 17792K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 2229K, capacity 2327K, committed 2432K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1.859 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 153088K, used 33905K [0x0000000719580000, 0x0000000724000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131584K, 9% used [0x0000000719580000,0x000000071a19c5f0,0x0000000721600000)
  from space 21504K, 99% used [0x0000000721600000,0x0000000722afff90,0x0000000722b00000)
  to   space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000722b00000,0x0000000722b00000,0x0000000724000000)
 ParOldGen       total 349696K, used 2922K [0x00000005cc000000, 0x00000005e1580000, 0x0000000719580000)
  object space 349696K, 0% used [0x00000005cc000000,0x00000005cc2da948,0x00000005e1580000)
 Metaspace       used 20849K, capacity 21190K, committed 21296K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2755K, capacity 2876K, committed 2944K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1.866 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 153088K, used 8950K [0x0000000719580000, 0x000000072c080000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131584K, 0% used [0x0000000719580000,0x0000000719580000,0x0000000721600000)
  from space 21504K, 41% used [0x0000000722b00000,0x00000007233bda20,0x0000000724000000)
  to   space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000721600000,0x0000000721600000,0x0000000722b00000)
 ParOldGen       total 349696K, used 2930K [0x00000005cc000000, 0x00000005e1580000, 0x0000000719580000)
  object space 349696K, 0% used [0x00000005cc000000,0x00000005cc2dc948,0x00000005e1580000)
 Metaspace       used 20849K, capacity 21190K, committed 21296K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2755K, capacity 2876K, committed 2944K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 1.866 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=3 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 153088K, used 8950K [0x0000000719580000, 0x000000072c080000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131584K, 0% used [0x0000000719580000,0x0000000719580000,0x0000000721600000)
  from space 21504K, 41% used [0x0000000722b00000,0x00000007233bda20,0x0000000724000000)
  to   space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000721600000,0x0000000721600000,0x0000000722b00000)
 ParOldGen       total 349696K, used 2930K [0x00000005cc000000, 0x00000005e1580000, 0x0000000719580000)
  object space 349696K, 0% used [0x00000005cc000000,0x00000005cc2dc948,0x00000005e1580000)
 Metaspace       used 20849K, capacity 21190K, committed 21296K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2755K, capacity 2876K, committed 2944K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1.897 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 153088K, used 0K [0x0000000719580000, 0x000000072c080000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131584K, 0% used [0x0000000719580000,0x0000000719580000,0x0000000721600000)
  from space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000722b00000,0x0000000722b00000,0x0000000724000000)
  to   space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000721600000,0x0000000721600000,0x0000000722b00000)
 ParOldGen       total 203264K, used 9244K [0x00000005cc000000, 0x00000005d8680000, 0x0000000719580000)
  object space 203264K, 4% used [0x00000005cc000000,0x00000005cc907158,0x00000005d8680000)
 Metaspace       used 20849K, capacity 21190K, committed 21296K, reserved 1067008K
  class space    used 2755K, capacity 2876K, committed 2944K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 3.215 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=4 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 153088K, used 104975K [0x0000000719580000, 0x000000072c080000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131584K, 79% used [0x0000000719580000,0x000000071fc03f68,0x0000000721600000)
  from space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000722b00000,0x0000000722b00000,0x0000000724000000)
  to   space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000721600000,0x0000000721600000,0x0000000722b00000)
 ParOldGen       total 203264K, used 9244K [0x00000005cc000000, 0x00000005d8680000, 0x0000000719580000)
  object space 203264K, 4% used [0x00000005cc000000,0x00000005cc907158,0x00000005d8680000)
 Metaspace       used 34962K, capacity 35420K, committed 35496K, reserved 1079296K
  class space    used 5109K, capacity 5270K, committed 5288K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 3.221 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=4 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 153088K, used 17106K [0x0000000719580000, 0x0000000727e80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131584K, 0% used [0x0000000719580000,0x0000000719580000,0x0000000721600000)
  from space 21504K, 79% used [0x0000000721600000,0x00000007226b4a80,0x0000000722b00000)
  to   space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000726980000,0x0000000726980000,0x0000000727e80000)
 ParOldGen       total 203264K, used 9252K [0x00000005cc000000, 0x00000005d8680000, 0x0000000719580000)
  object space 203264K, 4% used [0x00000005cc000000,0x00000005cc909158,0x00000005d8680000)
 Metaspace       used 34962K, capacity 35420K, committed 35496K, reserved 1079296K
  class space    used 5109K, capacity 5270K, committed 5288K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 3.221 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 153088K, used 17106K [0x0000000719580000, 0x0000000727e80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131584K, 0% used [0x0000000719580000,0x0000000719580000,0x0000000721600000)
  from space 21504K, 79% used [0x0000000721600000,0x00000007226b4a80,0x0000000722b00000)
  to   space 21504K, 0% used [0x0000000726980000,0x0000000726980000,0x0000000727e80000)
 ParOldGen       total 203264K, used 9252K [0x00000005cc000000, 0x00000005d8680000, 0x0000000719580000)
  object space 203264K, 4% used [0x00000005cc000000,0x00000005cc909158,0x00000005d8680000)
 Metaspace       used 34962K, capacity 35420K, committed 35496K, reserved 1079296K
  class space    used 5109K, capacity 5270K, committed 5288K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 3.312 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5 (full 2):
 PSYoungGen      total 153088K, used 0K [0x0000000719580000, 0x0000000727e80000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131584K, 0% used
```

..............
..............

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ask your customer if they have a God Mode shortcut created on their desktop or in another location. You can read more about it here. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/deploymentguys/2010/01/08/windows-7-godmode-and-other-folder-shortcuts/
Apparently, the short cut causes a problem with java applications throwing a msvcr100.dll+0x36adf. This was my issue with browsing for a file in a java app, or more specifically when the JFileChooser was used. There are other related errors to this as well. I will bump up your question since your link helped me to solve my issue.

Comment: Yes this was indeed it, very curious - sorry forgot to update this question but more details at http://blog.jthink.net/2017/05/beware-of-god-mode-on-latest-windows-10.html

Comment: @HopWorks This is astounding! Thank you so much for posting this answer! I could never have fond this. I installed the VCell cell simulator when got this error.

Comment: For the longest time I've been trying to help someone with this issue and we've chased the issue all over the place (reinstalled Java, reinstalled VC++ Redists, cleaned registry, gotten recommendations from the product's vendor, etc). It was an existing tool used at a large company that requires Java and has a "Browse Files" button. I'm still in shock that this ended up being the solution. Thank you for posting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

For people coming here from google, searching for solutions about the crashes in **Xilinx PlanAhead**, deleting the God Mode shortcut solve the issue with Java and msvcr100.dll

Comment: This is one of the strangest problems in my developer life :)

Comment: Also affects installation of Xilinx SDK 2016.2 (and possibly other versions).